# How to insert variable inside a Select statement

Tags: c#

```
string table = "City";
string query = "Select * from '"+table+"'";
```

> This gives me error stating incorrect symbol near ".

However,

```
string query = "Select * from City";
```

Gives the proper output.

Comment: replace single quotes with [ ] it should work

Comment: Did you check the output of query? Can you try this - string query = "Select * from "+table;

Comment: query = "Select * from " + table; but believe me this is insecure if your table variable is not a literal string. Do not build sql statements concatenating input received from any source.

Answer (score 5):

You just this

```
string query = "Select * from '"+table+"'";
```

to be replaced by

```
string query = "Select * from " + table;
```

Because you Query string is not `"Select * from City";` While it is forming    `"Select * from 'City'";`

and thus you getting error

Answer (score 3):

Best practice would be to use string.format

```
string table = "City";
string query = string.format("Select * from {0}", table);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to form your query like below.,

```
string table = "City";

//You don't need to have single quote...

string query = " Select * From " + table;
```

In order to use `Where` condition do like below.,

```
//Where clause only needs single quotes, to define the SQL parameter value in between...

string query = " Select * From " + table + " Where CityId = '" + cityId + "'";
```

Hope this helps.,

Answer (score 1):

Best-Practice should be **not to do this**, because it's susceptible to malicious SQL injection.

Anyway, if you have control over the `table` variable, you should do it as @madcow69 suggested, but I suggest to add the delimiters, so you always have a valid delimited identifier (for example if your table name is "order" or any other SQL reserved word).

```
string table = "City";
string query = string.format("Select * from [{0}]", table);
```

But what if `table` is the following?:

```
string table = "City]; DROP DATABASE [YourDB";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work like this:

```
string table ="City"
string query = "Select * from "+table;
```

Comment: @subhro, if it worked for you then kindly accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.,

```
string table = "City";

//You don't need to have single quote...

string query = " Select * From " + table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `.NET4.6` you could use the new "composite string formatting" feature introduced with `C# 6.0` [(read about it here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx).
this enables you to write your statement like this:

```
string query = $"Select * from {table}";
```

However I would **strongly** recommend not writing queries like that and use [sql parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7505842/1092181). this will help you avoid **SQL Injection attacks**.